# Does having an active operation coin cause you to play on different matchmaking servers?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If you're playing competitive matchmaking games, does having an coin for the active operation cause to to play on different servers than you would without?

Comment: I don't think it does but I have no evidence one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

If you select maps from the operation then you will be put on a server running one of those maps and you'll be playing with other people who also has the operation.

If you select the standard maps you can still be matched to play with people who haven't bought the operation.

Whether or not you equip the coin is irrelevant.

Comment: Although true before breakout, Operation Breakout's maps were available to all who had the [base] game. Buying breakout gave access to the coin, missions and the associated cases - not the maps.  This was a change made, presumably, to prevent segregation of the player base.